# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'swifter'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, swifter

I am trying to optimize apply() function that I using for calling a function which uses pandas dataframe as an argument. I am trying to call this using df_final = df.swifter.apply(function, axis=1).

Comment: `'swifter'` is not a column name in your frame

Comment: Did you install and import swifter? Show us the code.

Comment: I upgraded the pandas package that I was using, imported swifter and it worked.

Comment: `import swifter`. This is what I missed which was causing this error.